# How to execute a powershell with '-command' argument in administration mode

Tags: powershell

How can I run a powershell with -command parameters?

I tried adding '-Verb runAs', but I get a null valued expression.

```
powershell -Verb runAs -command "(Get-Date (Get-Process explorer).StartTime).ToString('yyyyMMdd')"
```

I open a powershell with admin right, the command

> (Get-Date (Get-Process explorer).StartTime).ToString('yyyyMMdd')

return a right value. But when I start a powershell without admin right, I get a null value.

So I think the problem is the 'powershell -Verb runAs' does not run the command in admin mode.

Note: I logged in as ad administer when I tried this.

Comment: There is a significant difference between logging in as a local administrator, and running a process as Administrator for UAC purposes. Are you ok with being presented with the typical UAC prompt to run something as an admin, or will this be running as a scheduled task that is running with elevated rights?

Comment: I have turned off UAC from control panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So elevating PowerShell's process can be done from within a script if you don't mind running a script instead of just executing a command. This will check if the process is already elevated, and if not it will re-launch the process with the RunAs verb so that it's running with elevated rights.

```
# Elevate UAC if not already running As Administrator
# Get the ID and security principal of the current user account
$myWindowsID=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$myWindowsPrincipal=new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($myWindowsID)

# Get the security principal for the Administrator role
$adminRole=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator

# Check to see if we are currently running "as Administrator"
if (!$myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))
{
    # We are not running "as Administrator" - so relaunch as administrator
    # Create an encoded string to re-launch the script bypassing execution policy
    $Code = ". '$($myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)'"
    $Encoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($code))

    # Indicate that the process should be elevated
    Start-Process PowerShell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "-EncodedCommand",$Encoded

    # Exit from the current, unelevated, process
    exit
}
# End UACElevation
```

The code is a little convoluted with the encrypting of the command and what not, but I found that I sometimes had issues with execution policy blocking me if I didn't do it this way. This avoids execution policy blocking PowerShell from running scripts, since it technically isn't running a script, just an encoded command. That command just happens to be for it to run a script once the PSSession is started.

Comment: Currently I have a perl script which get results from running a Powershell script  like this $result = `PowerShell -command 'my powershell statement needed to be executed in admin mode' '  .  How can I get the reults back if i switch to use the 'Start-Process'?

Comment: Save the above, followed by your code as a .ps1 file, then have perl execute `powershell.exe -file c:\path\to\script.ps1` (using your actual path). That should do it.